# realtime window remote connection?

Tags: remote-desktop

I am trying to control a desktop (HTPC) using my laptop. I currently use Teamviewer, but it is pretty slow. I used to use window remote desktop connection and it was pretty fast. The problem with window remote desktop connection is that it does not support realtime. By "Realtime", I mean it does not display what I am doing on the computer being controlled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you connected to the same user account through Windows RDC? I know on Windows Server 2003, RDC creates a new user session when you connect. You can see this by going to Task Manager > Users tab, and right click on the user you want to connect to and select "Connect". This will display changes to whatever users are connected to that session in "realtime".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean that you would like to be able to see what you're doing on the HTPC and your laptop at the same time.  You can try VNC, as it's the industry standard (more or less).  There's different distributions available (I always liked TightVNC but RealVNC is also common) that have lots of different compression types and other settings to optimize it.  I didn't find it as fast as Windows Remote Desktop Connection but it's pretty quick, especially if you're over a LAN (which I presume you are).

Comment: I would go with Ultra VNC if you went this route.  Real VNC is SO SLOW compared to Ultra VNC.

Comment: @typoknig - you have obviously never used RealVNC Enterprise.

Comment: No I have not used the Enterprise edition, why would I when there are free alternatives that do the same thing better available.  Read the reviews, Ultra VNC is almost always rated better than Real VNC.